# Centering contents name with [twocolumn] contents

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, two-column

I'm trying to make Table of Contents in two columns, but I'd like to center the contents name.

Now I'm doing

```
\twocolumn
\tableofcontents
```

but these commands give something like this:

```
Contents name   section 3
section 1       section 4 
section 2       section 5
```

while I'd like to obtain something like this:

```
    Contents name
section 1   section 3
section 2   section 4
```

I cant find out how can I achieve this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the documentclass is missing, I give an example for class `report` and for `article`. The redefinition for `\tableofcontents` merges the definitions of the original `\tableofcontents` with the definition for the environment `theindex`. The centering is done by smuggling in `\centering`.

Example for `report`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{report}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\tableofcontents}{%
  \if@twocolumn
    \@restonecolfalse
  \else
    \@restonecoltrue
  \fi
  \twocolumn[\@makeschapterhead{\centering\contentsname}]%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
          {\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \@starttoc{toc}%
  \if@restonecol
    \onecolumn
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foobar}
\section{Hello World}
\subsection{Subsection}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}
\chapter{Last chapter}
\section{Last section}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result for report]

Example for `article`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\tableofcontents}{%
  \if@twocolumn
    \@restonecolfalse
  \else
    \@restonecoltrue
  \fi
  \twocolumn[\section*{\centering\contentsname}]%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
          {\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \@starttoc{toc}%
  \if@restonecol
    \onecolumn
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Foobar}
\subsection{Hello World}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}
\section{Last section}
\subsection{Last subsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick and informative answer. I think it will work.