# Centred "Contents" in TOC in twocolumn document with custom sections

Tags: table-of-contents, two-column, titletoc

I want to adjust the TOC for my `twocolumn` document.  I want to have the word "Contents" at the top and centre of the page, and the toc entries following in two columns afterwards.

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72749/centering-contents-name-with-twocolumn-contents) which shows me how to do this; but

1) it conflicts with my use of the `titletoc` and `titlesec` packages.  This is because the TOC seems itself to be a section.

2) it is overly specific in formatting of the toc entries.
I would like to format the entries themselves with `titletoc` as follows

`\titlecontents{section} [0pt] { } {\thecontentslabel.\enspace} { } {\leaders\hbox to 1em{\hss.\hss}\hfill  \thecontentspage} []`

How can I get my formatting of the sections and toc entries, as well as centering the word "Contents" in the TOC of my doc?

The result so far is this
[image: Imgur]

The MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, bottom=2cm, columnsep=2.0cm,top=2cm, left=1in, right=1cm ] {geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[]{titletoc}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{4ex}{-0.5\parskip}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\raggedright\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesection.}{1ex}{}[]

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\tableofcontents}{%
  \if@twocolumn
    \@restonecolfalse
  \else
    \@restonecoltrue
  \fi
  \twocolumn[\section*{\centering\contentsname}]%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
          {\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \@starttoc{toc}%
  \if@restonecol
    \onecolumn
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\section{Section 3}
\section{Section 4}
\section{Section 5}
\section{Section 6}
\section{Section 7}
\section{Section 8}
\section{Section 9}
\section{Section 10}
\section{Section 11}
\section{Section 12}
\section{Section 13}
\section{Section 14}
\section{Section 15}
\section{Section 16}
\section{Section 17}
\section{Section 18}
\section{Section 19}
\section{Section 20}
\section{Section 21}
\section{Section 22}
\section{Section 23}
\section{Section 24}
\section{Section 25}
\section{Section 26}
\section{Section 27}
\section{Section 28}
\section{Section 29}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not as elegant as what you are trying, but:

Since the table of contents is only going to appear once, it's easy enough to [remove the header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55080/how-to-hide-the-table-of-contents-heading) and add a new one back in 'by hand'. Also, if you are mixing one-column and two-column elements, the `multicol` package is a little more flexible than setting the entire document to `twocolumn`.

EDIT: My original solution didn't work with `titlesec`, I think I was using the `section*` macro in a way that was incompatible with that package. This seems to work now, with a manually formatted toc heading.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{4ex}{-0.5\parskip}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\raggedright\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesection.}{1ex}{}[]

\usepackage[]{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section} [0pt] { } {\thecontentslabel.\enspace} { } {\leaders\hbox to 1em{\hss.\hss}\hfill  \thecontentspage} []

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
\@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\Large
\textbf{Contents}  
\end{center}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\section{Section 3}
\section{Section 4}
\section{Section 5}
\section{Section 6}
\section{Section 7}
\section{Section 8}
\section{Section 9}
\section{Section 10}
\section{Section 11}
\section{Section 12}
\section{Section 13}
\section{Section 14}
\section{Section 15}
\section{Section 16}
\section{Section 17}
\section{Section 18}
\section{Section 19}
\section{Section 20}
\section{Section 21}
\section{Section 22}
\section{Section 23}
\section{Section 24}
\section{Section 25}
\section{Section 26}
\section{Section 27}
\section{Section 28}
\section{Section 29}
\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

[image: LaTeX output]